Can I configure an ESXi physical NIC to be native to portgroup/VLAN?
I have an ESXi host that has four physical NICs, but only one is being used as a trunk port to the rest of the network. The Management VLAN (99) has an equivalent port group for the virtual machines and the ESXi host has a static address on the VLAN for its management services.  During a recent host/switch misconfiguration, I lost all access to the host, including the host management services, and had to connect a computer directly to the host. Creating a virtual interface on the locally connected computer to tag the traffic for the Management VLAN was an added complication.
After reverting the configuration change and ensuring everything was running again, I tried to configure one of the unused physical NICs to be native to the Management VLAN so a directly connected computer could access the host management services as well as the management IP’s of the virtual machines. Unfortunately, the option I tried (multiple port groups, etc.) did not work. It looked like the only viable path was to create a second VMKernel NIC with a second address for "local emergency" use, but this would limit the local connection to only access the ESXi management services and not the virtual machines too.
Am I missing a configuration that would let me use one of the physical NICs as native to the Management VLAN and allow access to both the ESXi host management services as well as any connected VMs on the Management VLAN when directly connected?

No, this is not possible.
You could keep a preconfigured physical switch with the necessary VLANs at hand for emergencies, but IMO just configuring the port on the computer is an quick and easy way to do that.

A specific port group on ESXi always tags frames or it never tags frames. You cannot differentiate by physical NIC.
So, if you want management VLAN frames untagged on one of the NICs, you must configure your network to run them untagged/native on all switch ports that the port group connects to. Don't forget standby NICs.
Of course, you could use a dedicated NIC with it's own port group as well. You could remove the management port group from the normal trunk and run a dedicate cable to the switch, without tagging.
Alternatively, instead of having to reconfigure a management computer, I'd use a nearby 'emergency' switch port to translate untagged management traffic to the tagged host trunk.
